react router dom v6 include a component within RouterProvider
I'm currently using react-router-dom v6 and I'm having trouble including a necessary component within the Router component as I'm not using BrowserRouter but using RouterProvider with createBrowserRouter.
import React from 'react'

// prettier-ignore
... Imports

const routes = createRoutesFromElements(
  <Route path='/' element={<RootLayout />}>
    <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
    <Route index element={<Landing />} />
    <Route path='auth' element={<Auth />} />
    <Route path='ideate' element={<IdeatorLayout />}>
      <Route path=':sessionID' element={<Display />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='privacy' element={<Privacy />} />
  </Route>
)

const router = createBrowserRouter(routes)

export const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  useAuthControl()

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router}>
      <ScrollToTop />
    </RouterProvider>
  )
}

Right now, I'm having an error including the ScrollToTop component within RouterProvider because I don't think RouterProvider takes in children props. I tried looking at documentations but I can't find the right way of doing this. My ScrollToTop component uses useHistory to check whenever the pathname has changed, and automatically scrolls to the top, so I have to include it within the router.
Thanks for the help in advance!

The RouterProvider component consumes no children prop.
Type Declaration:

declare function RouterProvider(
  props: RouterProviderProps
): React.ReactElement;

interface RouterProviderProps {
  fallbackElement?: React.ReactNode;
  router: Router;
  future?: Partial<FutureConfig>;
}


Typically you'd create a layout route component to render common UI components like the ScrollToTop.
Example:
import React from 'react'

// prettier-ignore
... Imports

const ScrollLayout = () => (
  <>
    <ScrollToTop />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const routes = createRoutesFromElements(
  <Route element={<ScrollLayout />}>
    <Route element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Landing />} />
      <Route path='auth' element={<Auth />} />
      <Route path='ideate' element={<IdeatorLayout />}>
        <Route path=':sessionID' element={<Display />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='privacy' element={<Privacy />} />
      <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter(routes)

export const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  useAuthControl();

  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}

It's also very likely you could render ScrollToTop as part of your RootLayout layout route component since it's also rendered at the root routing level.
